# Installing a new water pump - what to do about the gasket?

Tags: water-pump, gasket, gasket-maker

I'm replacing the water pump on a 1996 Toyota Tacoma, 2WD 4 cylinder. One of the videos I watched mentioned using gasket sealant when installing the new pump. I asked autozone for gasket sealant, but I got gasket maker (RTV Silicone Gasket Maker by Permatex) instead. The instructions on the gasket maker do not mention using an actual gasket. What is the best plan here? Use just the gasket maker only? Use the gasket maker with the felt gasket that came with the water pump? Get a new gasket altogether (the original was metal, the one I have is felt)? Go back and get gasket sealant and use that instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are basically the same thing. Use the gasket and put the gasket maker on either side of it. It will do the same job and work just as well. Don't put it on too thick, just enough to hold the gasket in place on the block or on the pump. Should leave you in good stead.

Comment: Thanks @Paulster2. Just to be absolutely clear - by "on either side", you mean only one side. The Gasket Maker I have recommends finger tightening the pump until the gasket material starts to squeeze out, then let dry for 1 hour before torquing it down. Then let cure for 24 hours before re-filling with coolant. Just wanted to make sure we were talking about the same thing - thanks!

Comment: I mean put the sealer on both sides of the gasket. Yes, tighten until you get a little squeeze, then set for the hour, then tighten to torque.